# C# Word Interop adding bottom border to paragraph creates a newline I want to get rid of

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop, border, newline

I'm trying to add a bottom border to my text in order to create an horizontal line just under it. Inserting the line is no problem, but I get a newline just before and don't know how to get rid of it.
I would like to insert the line right under my text and to find the cursor located in a new line right after it.

Does someone know how to do it?

Here's the code I'm working with at the moment:

```
object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
object oEndOfDoc = "\\endofdoc";

Word._Application oWord;
Word._Document oDoc;
oWord = new Word.Application();
oWord.Visible = false;
oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

oDoc.PageSetup.TopMargin = 36;
oDoc.PageSetup.RightMargin = 36;
oDoc.PageSetup.BottomMargin = 36;
oDoc.PageSetup.LeftMargin = 36;

Word.Paragraph titolo;
object oRng = oDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc).Range;
titolo = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref oRng);
titolo.Range.Text = "My text";
titolo.Range.Font.Name = "Open Sans";
titolo.Range.Font.Size = 16;
titolo.Range.Font.Italic = 0;
titolo.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
titolo.Format.SpaceAfter = 24;
titolo.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

Word.Paragraph section1_title;
oRng = oDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc).Range;
section1_title = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref oRng);
section1_title.Range.Text = "Text I want a line under";
            section1_title.Range.Borders[Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderBottom].LineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle;
section1_title.Range.Font.Name = "Open Sans";
section1_title.Range.Font.Size = 12;
section1_title.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft;
section1_title.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

oWord.Visible = true;
```

To make stuff clearer, [here is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IXK7.png) and [here is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEnAB.png). Notice that in the first picture I have a writable line between the text and the line (like I got a \n at the end of "My text").

I also tried to trim the text.

Thanks to anyone answering.

EDIT: Here's the [file](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Of4vUat2ZQFReoMOccDXxNikXL6P5Zmj/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=116706029488007333955&rtpof=true&sd=true) produced (GoogleDrive link)

EDIT2: Posted complete code. Needs Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word assembly reference to work and **using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;**

Comment: Sounds like you could write some simple code that reproduces the issue?  You know, copy paste and run it?  I'd also link the doc[x] as well.

Comment: The code I wrote down does reproduce the issue. I'll attach the docx, ty for the head's up

Comment: Complete code.  That does not compile as is, obviously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kind of found a solution to my problem: basically I took the text of the range of the paragraph and checked if there is an empty line and, in case I found it, I deleted it.

This is the code I added at the end of the one posted:

```
if (section1_title.Range.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
{
    section1_title.Range.Select();
    oWord.Selection.Delete();
}
```

I'm not sure this is the best way in doing this or if there is something else I could have done but, alas, it is working.